# Why is CMD prompt stating "set was unexpected at this time"

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to make a username change option for the settings in one of my batch file programs, but it keeps displaying a message like "set was unexpected at this time" which is weird, because my code seems right. It happens after entering a value for "cuser". None of the values I'm entering for input are null, since I've pre-declared the values at the beginning of the program to make it so I didn't have any null-value errors.

```
:uch
cls
echo.
echo Are you sure you want to change your username?
echo.
echo [Y/N]
echo.
set /p input=
if %input% EQU n goto set
if %input% NEQ y goto uch

:ucy
cls
echo.
echo Enter your current username
echo.
set /p cuser=
if %cuser% NEQ %username1% (
echo.
echo Incorrect username. Please try again.
echo Press any button to continue.
echo.
pause>null
goto :ucy
)
if %cuser% EQU %username1% (
echo Please enter new username.
echo.
set /p nuser=
echo Please enter again.
echo.
set /p nuser2=  
if %nuser2% EQU %nuser% set username1=%nuser%
if %nuser2% EQU %nuser% goto ga1
if %nuser2% NEQ %nuser% (
echo Usernames do not match. Please try again.  
echo Press any button to continue.
echo.
pause>null
goto ucy
)
goto ucy
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set value of variable inside if block without [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and the if is parsed with wrong syntax.And you have one unclosed bracket...

```
:uch
cls
echo.
echo Are you sure you want to change your username?
echo.
echo [Y/N]
echo.
set /p input=
if %input% EQU n goto set
if %input% NEQ y goto uch

:ucy
cls
echo.
echo Enter your current username
echo.
set /p cuser=
if %cuser% NEQ %username1% (
    echo.
    echo Incorrect username. Please try again.
    echo Press any button to continue.
    echo.
    pause>null
    goto :ucy
)
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if %cuser% EQU %username1% (
    echo Please enter new username.
    echo.
    set /p nuser=
    echo Please enter again.
    echo.
    set /p nuser2=  
    if !nuser2! EQU !nuser! set username1=!nuser!
    if !nuser2! EQU !nuser! goto ga1
    if !nuser2! NEQ !nuser! (
        echo Usernames do not match. Please try again.  
        echo Press any button to continue.
        echo.
        pause>null
        goto ucy
)

goto ucy
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the proper syntax for the `if` command. When comparing strings, use
`if "%var1%"=="%var2%"` to compare. `EQL NEQ` etc. are for numeric comparison.
You DO NOT need to have multiple `if` statements (one for yes and one for no) because, you can assume that if they didn't say `yes` then they meant to say no. Here is an improved script for you, one that doesn't need delayed expansion in order to work. Hope this helps.

```
:uch
cls
echo.
echo Are you sure you want to change your username?
set /p input=[Y/N]
if not "%input%"=="y" (goto ga1)
::THEY WANT TO CHANGE THEIR USERNAME
cls
echo.
set /p cuser=Enter your current username ^> 
if not "%cuser%"=="%username1%" (
echo.
echo Incorrect username. Please try again.
echo Press any button to continue.
pause>NUL
goto :uch
)
::THE USERNAME MATCHES
echo.
set /p nuser=Please enter new username. ^> 
echo.
set /p nuser2=Please enter again. ^>  
if "%nuser2%"=="%nuser%" (set username1=%nuser% && goto ga1)
echo Usernames do not match. Please try again.  
echo Press any button to continue.
echo.
pause>NUL
goto uch
:ga1
:://DO SOME OTHER STUFF HERE AFTER THEY CHANGED THEIR NAME OR OPTED NOT TO.
```